Accessing JSON's value from app metafield in liquid
Here's my sample JSON,
{
  car: {
    color: 'Red'
  },
  train: {
    color: 'Blue'
  }
}

I have added my JSON using metafieldsSet mutation. What I want to access is car's color or train's color from that metafield. But, doing {{ app.metafields.namespace.key.car }} returns null. Is this doable? If so, what am I missing?

You'll need access value first
{% assign metafield_value = app.metafields.namespace.key.value %}

Then, get json value as needed
{{ metafield_value.car.color }}

Or access directly if you don't wanna use variables
{{ app.metafields.namespace.key.value.car.color }}


thanks, it solved my problem. but, i couldn't find any doc on using value. can you link some docs?

@AbidHasan Here: https://shopify.dev/docs/api/liquid/objects/metafield#metafield-accessing-metafields-of-type-json
